# Replace double dot in string only when there are 2 dots

Tags: regex, sed, regex-group

I am new to SED but learning fast.
I am trying to replace 2 consecutive dots in a string with another string. The string should only 2 consecutive dots. The string is a qualified table name. The string is:

```
INNER JOIN DbName..TableName with (nolock)  -- comment with lots of dots ................
```

In the string only DbName..TableName should be replaced by DbName.PUBLIC.TableName
I tried using SED with the pattern:

```
sed s:\(.*\[a-zA-Z0-9\]\+\)\.\.(\[a-zA-Z0-9]\*):\1.PUBLIC.\2:gi
```

I thought this pattern would work but when I try it the same string is returned. I entered:

```
echo "INNER JOIN DbName..TableName with (nolock)  -- comment with lots of dots ................" | sed s:\(.*\[a-zA-Z0-9\]\+\)\.\.\(\[a-zA-Z0-9]\*\):\1.PUBLIC.\2:gi
```

The output from the command was the echo string. What am I doing wrong?

```
echo "INNER JOIN DbName..TableName with (nolock)  -- comment with lots of dots ................" | sed  s:\(.*\[a-zA-Z0-9\]\+\)\.\.\(\[a-zA-Z0-9]\*\):\1.PUBLIC.\2:gi
```

I was expecting:

```
INNER JOIN DbName.PUBLIC.TableName with (nolock)  -- comment with lots of dots ................"
```

Comment: You need to put the `sed` command argument inside quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/([^.])\.\.([^.])/\1.PUBLIC.\2/'
```

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `sed` argument inside quotes, otherwise `\.` becomes simply `.` when the shell processes the escape sequence.

```
sed 's/\.\./.PUBLIC./g'
```